# Как в php через сущность создать колонку с типом float с точностью до сотых

Tags: php, zend-framework, entity

Есть некая сущность. В ней формируем колонку, например: num

```
...
 /**
 * @var float
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", name="num", nullable=true)
 */
protected $num;
...
```

Сюда прилетает результат деления. Как ограничить точность до сотых? Есть [мануал](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html) , только я не понял как это применить в моем случае

Comment: `type="float(10,2)"` (общее количество цифр - сделать сколько нужно). И "результат деления" в момент "прилёта" ROUND-ить не забывать.

Comment: Тут "Прилет" не совсем обычный         $sql = 'UPDATE test_module tm SET tm.weight_percentage = (SELECT sumWeight FROM (SELECT 100/SUM(weight) sumWeight FROM test_module WHERE test_id =:test_id) tm1) * tm.weight WHERE km.kvip_id =:kvip_id';

Comment: Пробовал так. При попытке обновить базу ругается Unknown column type "float(3,2)" requested.

Comment: Это сообщение не принадлежит MySQL. Читайте, значит, мануал на фреймворк - это он тупит. А я в нём ни ухо ни рыло...

Comment: По вашим аннотациям я предполагаю, что вы используете `orm doctrine`, добавьте параметр `scale=2` к вашему полю

Comment: База обновилась без ошибок. Но точность до сотых не появилась.

Comment: @АлександрМаринов, забыл также упомянуть чтобы изменить поле `float` на `decimal`

Comment: @AntonKucenko, работает, но идет округление до целого числа. То есть, вместо 13.89 пишет 14.00

Comment: @АлександрМаринов `@ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, name="num", nullable=true)` попробуйте так

Comment: Больше информации вы можете найти по ссылке https://metanit.com/sql/mysql/2.3.php

Comment: @AntonKucenko, я туплю. Все работает. Спасибо. Запишите ваш комментарий в ответ со scale и decimal как ответ. Отмечу его как лучший

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, name="num", nullable=true)
```

Так же прочтите про `precision` чтобы потом не возникало проблем с количеством записываемых чисел